# Why does python append to all lists instead one when using one line list declaration(this: a = b = c = [])?

Tags: python, list

Python appends to all lists(like they are different pointer for the same memory address) when decalred with one line syntax(this: `a = b = c []`) but no such case with non-iterables or seperate declaration.

Same thing was causing a bug in my program when I used `append()`
and after some(a lot) debugging I found that this was causing the bug.

Example code with output:

```py
a = b = c = []
a.append(1)
b.append(2)

print("1st", a, b, c)
# Output: 1st [1, 2] [1, 2] [1, 2]

# But not with some other types or when reassigned
# Reassigning list
a = b = c = []
a = [1, 2, 3]

print("2nd", a, b, c)
# Output:2nd [1, 2, 3] [] []

# Multi-line for control
a = []
b = []
c = []
a.append(1)
b.apend(2)

print("3rd", a, b, c)
# Output:3rd [1] [2] []
```

Seperate output of program

> Output:
>   `1st [1, 2] [1, 2] [1, 2]`
>   `2nd [1, 2, 3] [] []`
>   `3rd [1] [2] []`

Are the lists something like different references but to the same memory address when assigned with one line syntax.

Comment: There aren't three lists, there's one list with three names.

Comment: @hobbs but that doesn't happen with integers?

Comment: Lists are references. Your variables all reference one list.

Comment: @Amiy: It happens with integers too. There's just no way to modify an integer, so you don't notice.

Comment: @mVChr no they are *lists*. *All variables* act like references in Python, regardless of the type of object they *happen* to be referring to.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. Lists are references. Your variables all reference one list.

Comment: If you will *replace* the reference to the list like you do it with an integer it would work as well. But you are *modifying` the list.

Comment: @mVChr *no*, `list` objects **are not references**. They *are lists*.

Comment: Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks, the paper is very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = b = c = []  # a, b, and c are assigned to the same list
```

The **first** is assigning those 3 variable names to the same list. Both appends are appending to the same list.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]  # a is assigned to a new list
```

In the **second**, `a` is getting assigned to a new list [1,2,3].

```
a = []  # a gets its own list
b = []  # b gets its own list
c = []  # c gets its own list
```

In the **third**, `a` `b` `c` are each assigned to their own lists.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking something similar that all lists point to same object when assigned with in line.

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

> like they are different pointer for the same memory address

They are, that is how python works in this instance.

Answer (score -2):

`list` instances are mutable, so the line

```
a = b = c = []
```

creates one list which is accessible through 3 different names.

This is not the case with non-mutable data structures (`tuple`, `int`, `str`).

Comment: Mutability is totally irrelevant. All Python objects have exactly the same semantics when it comes to assignment. Immutable types *simply don't expose mutator methods*.